# How to implement a "delivery receipt" for http requests

Tags: http, request, response, httpresponse

Is there a way to implement a "delivery receipt", or, "quick response", from the server before the start of a long running process (that will delay the actual response content)?
I mean this:

```
request -> server receives -> res.send(200) ((but keep this 'res' alive!)) -> server long running process -> res.send("actual response")
```

This would be very useful in the app side, so I get to know that timeouts are really happening because of the process and not because the server is offline. Also, I wanted to avoid making two requests, one following the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Status Code 100 CONTINUE can be used for this purpose. See https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.1.1

According to the RFC, 100 Continue is an interim response which must be followed by a final response once the request has been completed.

Comment: But is this just a convention? Or we have implemented resources do deal with this kind of feature?  I mean, will I have to make a request, receive the status 100 then make another request for the actual content?

Comment: No, the flow would be "client request with `Expect: 100-continue` header without request body" - "server response `100 Continue`" - "client sends body" - "server processes body" -" server sends response `200 OK`/`500 Internal serve error`accordingly". The whole transmission takes place within the same HTTP connection. So the client will get two responses from the server within the same connection.